# Adding data to a list in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Am receiving data in form of `{room1: 4, room2: 2}`

received in a name of roomData

```
$scope.testdata = [{
        'room': 'room0',
        'users': '10'
    }];

$scope.setLobbyRoom = function (roomData) {

    $scope.inc = 0;
    for (i in roomData) {
        //want to push the data into the array list here.
    }
}
```

Comment: which object you want to push data in and what form of object you want finally?

Comment: I need push the roomdata "{room1: 4, room2: 2} " to testdata. which is used for repeat.

Comment: If rooomData is an array of data like this {romo1: 4, room2:2}, How come
You first data in testData i ssomething like {'room' : 'room0', 'users' : '10'}, while its should be something like testData = [ {room1:4, room2:2}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push the data to $scope.testdata, all you have to do is to use the method push

```
$scope.testdata = [{
        'room': 'room0',
        'users': '10'
    }];

$scope.setLobbyRoom = function (roomData) {

    $scope.inc = 0;
    for (i in roomData) {
        $scope.testdata.push(roomData[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `roomData` an array? If so, it's as simple as:

```
$scope.testData = $scope.testData.concat(roomData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.testdata = [];

$scope.setLobbyRoom = function (roomData) {
    $scope.testdata = [];
    for (i in roomData) {
        $scope.testdata.push({
            room: i,
            users: roomData[i] 
        });
    }
}
```

This works